# Why Collection showing only first field value

Tags: sales-order, collection-filtering

I am just new to Magento and trying to get collection from sales/order_item model
i don't know whether i am asking it right way or not but i am having following problem in getting values from db in magento 1.9.0.1

My db table looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
item_id    order_id    customid   ...... remaining column .....
   1           1           1
   2           2           1
   3           2           2
   4           2           1
   5           3           1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what i am trying to do is to  get customid from order_id value which i have.

but it's showing only first value of customid which is 1 if order_id is 2

i am using below code

```
public function getCustomValue()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $collections = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $id);
        foreach ($collections as $c) {
            $customid = $c->getCustomid();
        }
        return $customid;
    }
```

So if i use

```
echo $this->getCustomValue();
```

it shows 1 only.

but as in my table order_id got 3 entry with 1,2,1 customid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logic issue in your code,you need to return array.Please  $customid as Array type variable.

```
public function getCustomValue()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $collections = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $id);
    // define as array varible
    $customid=array();

        foreach ($collections as $c) {
        // assign the value at array
            $customid[] = $c->getCustomid();
        }
        return $customid;
    }
```

Comment: @Bera thanks for your response bera. but could you tell me how to use it in .phtml file.

as if i use echo $this->getCustomValue() it display Array word only...

but if i change return $customid to print_r($customid)
it displays Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )

Comment: yes. it is give the value on this format as i told you function return array value

Comment: is getCustomValue() is block or model class function

Comment: it's a class function Bera..

Just wanna know how to use it with any if condition like suppose

$a = 2;

and i use it with if condition

if ($a == $this->getCustomValue) {
    // do this
}

how to do that

Comment: as you use array then you need use if(in_array($a,$this->getCustomValue()))

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help Bera... I accept ur solution as an answer as it's my lack of knowledge is what not allowing me to get what i want.

but i would like to know why if i use "return $customid" it echo just "Array" only and not any value like 121, which i get if i replace "return $customid" to print_r($customid). I believe it should be passed in return case too...

but anyway thanks a ton for your help Bera